# Usage of "to" vs "from"

Tags: prepositions, collocations

While writing a cover letter, I wrote a following a sentence.

"I am confident that I possess the pertinent skills to successfully complete this course and am one opportunity away **to** making a significant contribution to the community in upcoming years."

Is it correct?

or should have I written the following?

"I am confident that I possess the pertinent skills to successfully complete this course and am one opportunity away **from** making a significant contribution to the community in upcoming years."

Which one of the above is correct?

Comment: Sorry, you should have written _from_. You can take a step _towards_ something or be another day _closer to_ an event but you can only be a distance (in space or time) _away from_ something. _Away from_ is the antonym of _closer to_.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.  You can say either

> I am one opportunity away from making a significant contribution

or you can say

> I am close to making a significant contribution

Similar to the first sentence is:

> The bullet came within a hair of hitting the aorta.